# Robolectric accessing database throws an error

Tags: android, android-sqlite, robolectric

I have a test that creates an activity which attempts to get some data from the database. This fails with SQLiteException

```
17:40:40.528 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Cannot open SQLite connection, base error code: 14
17:40:40.528 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSQLiteConnection.rethrow(ShadowSQLiteConnection.java:53)
17:40:40.528 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSQLiteConnection.access$600(ShadowSQLiteConnection.java:30)
17:40:40.529 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSQLiteConnection$Connections.execute(ShadowSQLiteConnection.java:443)
17:40:40.529 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSQLiteConnection$Connections.open(ShadowSQLiteConnection.java:345)
17:40:40.529 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(ShadowSQLiteConnection.java:58)
17:40:40.529 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(SQLiteConnection.java)
17:40:40.529 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
17:40:40.529 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
17:40:40.529 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
17:40:40.530 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
17:40:40.530 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
17:40:40.530 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
17:40:40.530 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
17:40:40.530 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
17:40:40.530 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:1142)
17:40:40.530 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:267)
17:40:40.531 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
17:40:40.531 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
```

This used to work fine before I moved my database class to a singleton model. Any suggestions how this should be handled with Robolectric? I couldn't find any documentation or samples on this.

EDIT:

Running Robolectric 3.0 RC-2

Robolectric is driving my activity which attempts to do some work with the database. 
In my app DB class, removing the check for instance == null from below 'fixes' the issue (i.e. there's no issue with Robolectric running the test if MySQLiteOpenHelper is recreated every time)

```
public static synchronized MyDataManager getInstance(Context context){
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new MyDataManager(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
}

private MyDataManager(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(context);
}
```

MySQLiteOpenHelper is a simple extension of SQLiteOpenHelper.

The failure is happening on (again, this is inside by db class):

```
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Obviously I don't really want to recreate a connection every time in my App - and I think nobody would want that? Which makes me think there should be a way to do this properly in Robolectric and I'm just missing a trick here?

EDIT:

Also, the test runs successfully in isolation, which makes me think it's something to do with Robolectric moving between the test cases and reusing the database connection?

Both tests don't do ANYTHING specific to database or related to any of the DB classes. First test starts a fragment which will access the database to write some data. Second test is failing on attempt to open the db as above.

Comment: Show us the code. What version of robolectric?

Comment: Which code would help? There's not much I changed between failing/passing runs - just wrapped my DB class into a singleton model

Comment: I see you already found: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1622. I always ask for code to get a better understanding.

Comment: @JaredBurrows fair enough. yeah sorry for posting in both places - wasn't sure if that's a bug or I'm not using Robolectric correctly... I've added some code if that helps...

Comment: Nah it really doesn't because you are holding back a lot of it. Are you using `application` for your context?

Comment: It's in the code above - `context.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: No, that is your "code" and not your "test". How are you testing your code? Where is your code (eg. `MyDataManagerTest`)?

Comment: Well, there isn't. I'm not testing the MyDataManager - I'm testing a small part of the activity. All this is a side effect because the activity has a loader which goest straight after the DB on data fetch. I'll post my test in a sec

Comment: @JaredBurrows I've double checked and the failing test works fine in isolation. It fails only after another test which starts a fragment which writes to a database. There are no explicit calls to the db from test cases, both tests use the same `mActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(StartupActivity.class);` cleaning up with `mActivity.finish()` after the test.

Comment: `work fine before I moved my database class to a singleton model` <-- reset all singleton instances between each test or you will get side effects like yours. Instead of singletons you should try weak reference ;)

Comment: @nenick is there a way in Robolectric to reset everything between tests? Also - weak references for SQLiteOpenHelper - wouldn't that cause resource-heavy reconnection each time it's GCed?

Comment: No you must reset your singletons self. Example can be found here https://github.com/nenick/QuAcc/blob/master/AppCT/src/test/java/de/nenick/robolectric/RoboComponentTestBase.java. When do you expect resource-heavy reconnection? At app runtime this should not happen often and at testing we should use a clean database for each test. in memory database could be faster.

Comment: @nenick Perfect - that's exactly what I was looking for!! Can you please copy/paste this as an answer so that I could select it? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reset all singleton instances between each test or you will get side effects like yours.

```
@After
public void finishComponentTesting() {
    resetSingleton(YourSQLiteOpenHelper.class, "sInstance");
}

private void resetSingleton(Class clazz, String fieldName) {
    Field instance;
    try {
        instance = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        instance.setAccessible(true);
        instance.set(null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you going to droidcon in Berlin? It would be nice to meet you. About answer - you know that this is wrong black magic :)

Comment: I don't have tickets yet but I (or my employer) will order some. Yeah would be nice to meet you too ;) and no that is no `wrong` black magic it's just the nature of singletons which force us to use this kind of magic ;)

Comment: Cool, would be great! Take a look to Dagger and you will frget about this black magic. Basically client code must not know where, how, who and "is singlethon" about own dependency

Comment: I never looked how the singleton mechanism works with dagger because I prefer androidannotations. Is there a site where this is explained? We plan to use singletons with weak references but I'm not sure if this will avoid the manual reset between tests.

Comment: Let us talk on conference. Short - I don't like AA "magic" generated activity with _. You don't have this code but should reference it in Manifest. Sure apt from Hugo includes sources that they are visible by AS. But still. With Dagger singlethons are not real singlethons but close to. Weak reference will not safe you from manual reseting

Answer (score 1):

IMO you have to remove/replace database usage/singlethons with dependency injection and mock them in tests. In this case you don't need to instantiate things that are not used in your code/tests.

Sounds like dummy suggestion and something that requires more effort than "just to fix current state". But my experience it is worth to do and it will lead for clear design and testing for entire application.

As for me it is comparable to (sorry again for obvious examples):

1. `Debug` vs `Unit testing`
2. Fixing OEM with preventing memory leaks

Comment: You mean injecting SQLiteOpenHelper into the class? Wouldn't that cause multiple connections to the DB? I was under impression that there should be just one SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: I mean abstracting your model from SQL and injecting something this abstraction into UI

Comment: I'm not sure that would work as underneath there would still be a single SQLiteOpenHelper. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding you - can you provide an example?

Comment: Maybe this article will inspire you https://medium.com/@artem_zin/m-model-from-mvc-mvp-in-android-flow-and-mortar-bd1e50c45395