# Resetting between Robolectric tests

Tags: android, robolectric

I have a suite of Robolectric tests for my Android application, all of which run green.

I'm adding a new test, around the behaviour of a fragment. When I add this test, related tests in another test class around a different fragment start failing.

Only test code has changed. This implies to me that there is some shared state between these two screens, I am happy to go and hunt that down and fix it. In the mean time however I'm trying to work out how to completely reset Robolectric between tests.

Is this possible? Can you clear down state held in the Application, statics/singletons and databases in Robolectric. I've tried `Robolectric.reset()` without much luck. I'm using Robolectric 3.0.

Comment: Most probably you have static data in your app that is reshared. I would not reset Robolectric but pay attention to fixing the test. In my experience having dependent tests is sign for architecture design issues

Comment: I understand that I could reset the various caches I have in the app between tests (in a `@After` for example) to make them truely independent, and this is probably the better solution. However I'm still interested to know if its possible to reset state via Robolectric rather than my own code.

Comment: Singleton instances aren't reseted between tests. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/30330170/3619179

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should recreate objects or reset their test in `@Before` so that all tests run in isolation.

Comment: please explain more about how to run in isolation