# Why RobolectricGradleTestRunner on Android is producing exception for more than two test cases?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I have been worked with the `Framework Robolectric` with `Android` and `Gradle`. I did some unit testing using appropriate build variants (Unit Tests) approach.

However, I am unable to get success status for my test `MyAppConfigurationActivityTest` that includes two 
individual test cases `testMyAppConfigurationActivity_NotNull` and `testMyAppConfigurationActivity_GetListNotNull`.

When I ran my `MyAppConfigurationActivityTest` I get the exception depicted below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal connection pointer 216. Current pointers for thread Thread[pool-4-thread-1,5,main] []
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSQLiteConnection$Connections.execute(ShadowSQLiteConnection.java:470)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSQLiteConnection.nativeResetStatementAndClearBindings(ShadowSQLiteConnection.java:286)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeResetStatementAndClearBindings(SQLiteConnection.java)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.releasePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:915)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:519)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.__constructor__(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseConnection.queryForOne(AndroidDatabaseConnection.java:190)
at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedQueryForId.execute(MappedQueryForId.java:38)
at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.queryForId(StatementExecutor.java:85)
at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.queryForId(BaseDaoImpl.java:223)
at com.j256.ormlite.dao.RuntimeExceptionDao.queryForId(RuntimeExceptionDao.java:84)
at com.sample.android.ui.MyAppConfigurationActivity.onCreate(MyAppConfigurationActivity.java:105)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:195)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:122)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:304)
at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$2.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:45)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:118)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:129)
at com.sample.android.ui.tests.activity.MyAppConfigurationActivityTest.testMyAppConfigurationActivity_NotNull
```

The strange point is that exception is being launched only when I ran the class
`MyAppConfigurationActivityTest`.

In another hand, when I ran individually each test case `testMyAppConfigurationActivity_NotNull` or 
`testMyAppConfigurationActivity_GetListNotNull` none exception is launched.

Any idea about this ?

I really appreciate any help about this question.

Comment: Looks like a common issue with some singleton classes, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30330170/3619179